# I need helping using iAds in my application, How do I put iAds in while using sprite builder?

Tags: ios, ios7, ads, iad, spritebuilder

I need helping using iAds in my application. I currently am not using any storyboards. I am using Sprite Builder for my UI.

I attached an image to show all the different file name I have.

The "iAdViewController.h & .m" files are just example codes I looked up and was messing with so that my iAd can work.

I keep trying to learn how to do it but nothing seems to be what I want.

How would I go about simply putting iAds at the bottom of the screen while using
Sprite Builder for my user interface?

image here: https://discussions.apple.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-25162857-394216/Screen+Shot+2014-03-14+at+12.11.14+AM.png

Answer (score -1):

In xCode place the iADs code in your project and in the project setting enable iADs under capabilities.